# Two non isotopic symplectic forms on the Torus

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

Part 1 - How can I find two non isotopic symplectic forms on $\mathbb T^2$ ?

All I know is that the usual symplectic form on $\mathbb R^2$ can be "projected" onto $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ thereby giving "a" symplectic form.

Part 2 - Are these symplectic forms symplectomorphic?

Comment: Trivial examples would be two forms with different integrals or two forms with opposite orientations.

Comment: right. but they would be neither symplectomorphic nor isotopic right?
can I find two forms that are symplecto but not isotopic?

Comment: $\omega$ and $-\omega$ are symplectomorphic. I suggest, you edit your question to make it clear what exactly you are asking. In general, if $\omega_1, \omega_2$ are area forms on $T^2$ such that $\omega_1/\omega_2>0$ and $[\omega_1]=[\omega_2]$, then these forms are isotopic.

Comment: Oh I see. So the answer to part 1 is any orientation form w and -w.

Comment: Are there two non symplectomorphic forms on T²?

Comment: As I said, if $|\int_S \omega_1|\ne |\int_S \omega_2|$ then the forms $\omega_1, \omega_2$ on a surface $S$ cannot be symplectomorphic.